# UK visitor visa sponsorship letter

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I am an Indian citizen applying for a visitor visa to UK for tourist purpose. I'll be accompanying my husband who will be visiting UK for business work for 1 week and he'll be sponsoring my trip (his trip is sponsored by the company).
Do I need to get a letter from my husband stating that he'll be sponsoring my trip or just mentioning this in the Visa application would suffice?
Are there any other documents required to support the application?
Do I need to attach my bank statements as well?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk? You are the applicant, not your husband, you need to supply all the documents listed that are relevant to you plus a letter from your husband and his documents.

Comment: What is your citizen ship ?

Comment: @Matt I've added in the question now. I'm an Indian citizen.